# Error al hacer Run file de un formulario

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Me sale este comunicado en la caja de texto. Posiblemente haya un error en este código:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

```
public class Conexion_DB {
Connection cn = null;

    public Connection conectarDB(){
        try{
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost3306/tienda2022","root","12345678");
        } catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return cn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que tu problema este en que te falta añadir `:` entre el hostname y el puerto de la conexion de la DDBB... Tienes:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost3306/tienda2022` y deberia ser: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tienda2022`